# Test of OTA firmware update using BLE on an ESP32 (ESP-IDF)

Tags: testing, bluetooth-lowenergy, firmware, ota

I'm doing a project where I have to develop OTA firmware update using BLE (not WiFi) on an ESP32 (ESP-IDF). I'm still in the design phase and I'm wondering how I'm going to test my code. Is there any android/iPhone applications or 3. party programs on the computer, that allows me to perform a test OTA firmware update?

I'm not the developer of the products smartphone application.

Comment: I only know about the nRF Connect app, but it expects you to use the OTA DFU services from nordic. I know nothing about the OTA protocol you are using, but it might me sufficient to convert your update file to hex, split it into multiple parts and send it with a app of your choice to your characteristic

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about ESP-IDF, I'm using Arduino. I implemented OTA via BLE on ESP32 with an android app. The Arduino code and android app is available on GitHub: [BLE_OTA_Arduino](https://github.com/fbiego/ESP32_BLE_OTA_Arduino)

Comment: I'm actually looking at your app and code at the moment. Some translating from Arduino to ESP-IDF is needed as it is a requirement that I use ESP-IDF so I'll get to work. Thank you!

Comment: Hi fbiego. I don't really understand the android app. It keeps saying "set up mac address" even after I establish connection with the ESP32 from the phones BT settings. Am I doing anything wrong? How do I set up mac address?

Comment: I have not implemented pairing in the app. First you have to pair in the phones BT settings then you can select it in the app. Remember the ESP32 name must have "ESP" in it's bluetooth name

Comment: I added "ESP" to the name and it now shows up. But now another problem. When choosing the binary file, the application stops working instantly. Tried on 2 separate android phones. Any ideas?

Comment: I have not tested with Android 10+, there might be issues with the file picker.

Comment: If I acquire a smartphone with an older Android version, which version would you recommend for testing your app?

Comment: I have tested it on Android 7 & it works fine. It should work on Android 5 - 9.

Comment: @Bas10an have you managed to convert the code to ESP-IDF??

Comment: @ArnyminerZ I'm bound by NDA so I can't give you much. But I can give you my primary inspiration from [chegewara's github](https://github.com/chegewara/esp32-OTA-over-BLE) and [github issue](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/issues/2075). I used [this web bluetooth application](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/esp32-ota-updates-over-ble-from-a-react-web-application/all) written in javascript for testing. It's not much but I hope it helps :)